# Problems running ClamAV on Centos 5.6 with PHP 5.2.17

Tags: php, centos

I'm having some issues using ClamAV from PHP using the php-clamav package on Centos 5.6, I am wondering if anyone might be able to shed any light on setup?

Installing ClamAV (and clamav-devel) seemed to go ok, and the freshclam command gives me some encouraging looking output. Adding php-clamav also seemed to go fine. Adding extension=clamav.so to my php.ini file adds a clamav section to the output from phpinfo(). I then created a /etc/php.d/clamav.ini that looks like this:

```
[clamav]
clamav.dbpath="/var/clamav"
clamav.maxreclevel=16
clamav.maxfiles=10000
clamav.maxfilesize=26214400
clamav.maxscansize=104857600
clamav.keeptmp=0
clamav.tmpdir="/tmp"
```

/var/clamav is where the files bytecode.cvd, daily.cld, main.cvd abd mirrors.dat can be found, I assume that's what it's looking for?

Restarting Apache causes these details to display in phpinfo(), but only the first time I try. Subsequent calls to that function do not produce anything. Additionally, calls to cl_info() always show the ClamAV version but "0 virus signatures loaded".

I feel like I'm very close...any help would be much appreciated!

Toby

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Clamav PHP extension: virus definitions missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263745/php-clamav-php-extension-virus-definitions-missing) (Not solved).

Comment: Thanks for that - unfortunately that post contains no answers/useful information...apologies if that's still a reason for not posting, seems not to me though.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. I have accepted one previous answer (I hadn't realised that I'd omitted to do so), unfortunately that's the sum total of useful answers so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Belatedly, but in case it helps anyone, at the author's (php-clamav) suggestion I made a new version from the SVN repo, which fixed the issue. I believe the author has since released a new version based on the same code.